# univariable significance lost when combining variables together

Tags: survival, cox-model

Analysing data from a past experiment I found that size of animals and a level of serum biomarker were associated with time to death when considered separately. Though when combining them in a cox model both the variable lost significance. How should I interpret and report this? Is it correct (and also relevant in scientific terms) to affirm that univariable association is lost when analysing both variables in a multivariable cox model?

Comment: Is it possible that size and market are collinear?

Comment: The correlation is 0.65 with a p of 0.004 using the spearman test, could this be the reason?

Comment: Possible dups: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57423/why-is-anova-interaction-no-longer-significant-after-including-a-covariate,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27257/significant-predictors-become-non-significant-in-multiple-logistic-regression,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269976/is-it-possible-to-lose-significance-for-categorical-variables-when-changing-the,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157475/model-change-after-switching-reference-level-in-r-logistic-regression-model-with