# Is it possible to lose significance for categorical variables when changing the reference level?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, mixed-model, categorical-data

Suppose we have two categorical variable: **C** and **B**. **C** has 3 `levels(0,1,2)` and **B** has 3 `levels(0,1,2)`. Each participant is exposed to each of these variables under a latin square design such that under each session each participant experiences all the three levels under category **C** and also all the three levels under category **B**. I also introduce participant ID as the random effect to account for any individual differences. I fit a mixed effects model against a certain prediction P in the following way:

```
mixed.model.out = lmer(P ~ C*B + (1|pid), data=data,REML=F)
```

Luckily, when I ran the above model, I found a significant main effect from **C** as in, the coefficient of the contrast 0-1 and 0-2 are significant. I used the `lmerTest` library to check for significances.

But, when I changed the reference level for **B** from 0 to 1, I lost the significance for the contrast variables in **C** that I earlier found to be significant. 
Why is this happening? 
I also dropped the random effect and fit a simple lm model and I observe a similar trend where I lose significance for the contrasts when I change the baseline for variable **B**. Unfortunately I can't share my exact numbers but if anyone has run into similar issues I would highly appreciate your feedback.

Here are a few other **backup tests** I ran to check if the main effects I was expecting are in fact there or not.

```
mixed.model.null = lmer((1|pid), data=data,REML=F)

mixed.model.B = lmer(B+(1|pid), data=data,REML=F)

mixed.model.C = lmer(C+(1|pid), data=data,REML=F)

mixed.model.BCinter = lmer(B*C+(1|pid), data=data,REML=F)

mixed.model.BCnointer = lmer(B+C+(1|pid), data=data,REML=F)

anova(mixed.model.null,mixed.model.C): Significant

anova(mixed.model.null,mixed.model.B): Not Significant

anova(mixed.model.BCinter,mixed.model.BCnointer): Significant
```

Comment: This question is not presented very clearly.

Comment: to answer the question in the title: yes, of course it's possible. The p-values for the individual terms are testing a completely different hypotheses when you change the reference level.